# accessing file with react native expo

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am making a React Native game using Expo and trying to use a word list words.txt. I've put it in the Assets folder. I have tried many ways to do this, using e.g. expo-file-system and expo-asset, but with each I get an error like "module not recognised". Can someone who has done this before help me out?

```
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system"
import { Asset } from "expo-asset"
...
const Main = () => {
    const [wordList, setWordList] = useState([])
      useEffect(() => {
    // const readWordList = async () => {
    //   try {
    //     const path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/words.txt"
    //     const content = await RNFS.readFile(path, "utf8")
    //     setWordList(content)
    //   } catch (error) {
    //     console.error("Error reading file:", error)
    //   }
    // }
    // readWordList()
    async function readFile() {
      try {
        const asset = Asset.fromModule(require("../assets/myFile.txt"))
        await asset.downloadAsync()
        const fileUri = asset.localUri
        const fileContent = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(fileUri)
        console.log("File content:", fileContent)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error reading file:", error)
      }
    }
    readFile()
  }, [])
...
```